# Использование Google Places API для поиска объектов в системе по местоположению (адресу)

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api

Я использую Google Places javascript api v3 для сохранения местоположения объектов. В базу записываю значения lat и lng.
К сожалению, я не обнаружил в классе [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) поля radius либо чего-нибудь подобного для определения, попадает ли точка с заданными координатами (lat, lng) в окрестности данного места/адреса. Возможно ли это в принципе при использовании данного сервиса или нужно смотреть в сторону других вариантов? Если возможно, прошу подсказать, каким образом это реализовать.